# Blog page content not display properly

Tags: wordpress, margin, blogs

I have upgraded Wordpress, Avada and child theme.

After the upgrade, the image post (left) and post content (right) are not aligned but displaying in step down of each other.

I checked with Chrome Inspector and when I untick the `margin`, the page content is aligned properly.

I have compared the `margin` values and the blog options of the live site with development site and they both matching in the `style.css` showing the following.

```
.fusion-blog-pagination .fusion-post-content {
    margin-left: 430px !important;
}
```

however on the live site they display the page properly but not on the development site.

I also tried to change the `margin` values in the `style.css` however the setting not affecting the page, inspector show 430px left. How can I fix it? is there any settings i’m missing?

FYI: the my WP website copy is installed on my local server using docker WP V5.4.1/PHP_7.4/Apache image.

Comment: There isn't enough information here for us to help. Can you create a a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see what's happening? Without seeing the relevant code and style, its impossible for us to see what has gone wrong. Have you checked the styles of the inner and outer elements of `.fusion-post-content`? They can also affect how they appear.  Also, what do you mean by "untick the merging"?

Comment: Hi @FluffyKitten, sorry typo(fixed it) i meant  tick/untick 'margin-left' in the inspector reproduce the issue. i have very basic knowledge in css and html but can follow instructions. i have made the site live, Can i PM the URL in this website? if you use inspector when pointing on the paragraph> find the <div class="fusion-post-content post-content" then untick/tick on the mergin-left you can see it live. i think you can see the css and html codes. will that help to examen the issue?

Comment: i have just tried to remove this code and the problem gone, will that affect other areas or its ok to remove it?                                                                                             .fusion-blog-pagination .fusion-post-content {
    margin-left: 430px !important;
}